# There are always an error when I using h2o rest api to get models information

Tags: java, rest, h2o

I created some models in web ui like this:
[image]

But when I want to get all models information in rest api, it shows that "NullPoiterException".
[image]

ps: The api to import file is ok.
[image]

Comment: @Jens this user does not ask "what is NPE", but rather, why it is thrown in this concrete scenario. As such, it is probably not a duplicate, and certainly not with the one indicated above his question. Please consider removing the mark.

Comment: @PetrKozelka It is a duplicate, because with out code we can only help to teach OP in what is a NPE and how can he fix it

Comment: @Jens if you miss something, ask the user to add it. Missing information does not turn a question into a duplicate. Or, maybe you can provide links to SO codex or discussions in meta, that support your approach?
Right now, you just prevented people who can help, to share the answer (and get credit for it), for a reason that is apparently false.